# HttpContext doess not contain definition for Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

```
public static IOwinContext CurrentContext
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
    }
}
```

for this method i have facing problem that Httpcontext does not contain definition for Current

i have added System.aspnetcore.selfhost nuget package which supported system.web but its also not worked

```
public static class OwinContextExtensions
{

    public static int GetClientID()
    {
        int result = 0;
        var claim = CurrentContext.Authentication.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ClientID");

        if (claim != null)
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt32(claim.Value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static IOwinContext CurrentContext
    {
        get
        {
            **return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();//here getting error**
        }
    }
}
```

how to write return for this method `public static IOwinContext CurrentContext`

Comment: `System.Web` is not used in ASP.NET Core, so I’m not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: @poke thaks for comment i am new in asp.net core so i am just following this http://blog.geveo.com/OAuth-Implementation-for-WebAPI2

Comment: That tutorial is for ASP.NET 4, not ASP.NET Core. You might benefit from throwing it out and finding an ASP.NET Core tutorial to follow instead. :)

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks for your comment. i would appreciate if you guyz give me link for oauth 2.0 implementation code for asp.net core. please help me

Comment: You should check out the ASP.NET Core documentation, in particular the [security chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to get an idea how you can integrate other authentication providers into your application.

Comment: For oauth 2.0 implementation code for asp.net core , you could refer to the [Authenticate with OAuth 2.0 in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/) and [Secure Your ASP.NET Core App with OAuth 2.0](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/12/secure-your-aspnet-core-app-with-oauth) which may be helpful .

Comment: @XueliChen i had go with this and done the same.its good till the end. i had one issue in this my page doesnt open authorizaion window in this ,it directly redirected to me on github link.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET the **HttpContext** is a transient object, which is created once for each request; but the service should be registered as a singleton (thanks to @poke for this remark). Outside a controller, use dependency injection to sort things out. Define a static class similar to:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace.Services
{
    public static class MyAppContext
    {
        private static readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            // ...
        }

        public static int GetClientID()
        {
            int result = 0;
            var claim = CurrentHttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ClientID");
            if (claim != null)
            {
                result = Convert.ToInt32(claim.Value);
            }
            return result;
        }

        // You can even expose the current HTTP context
        public static HttpContext CurrentHttpContext { get { return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; } }
    }
}
```

In **Startup.cs**, configure the service:

```cs
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // if using .NET Core 2.1 or above use:
        // services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        var ctx = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        YourNamespace.Services.MyAppContext.Configure(ctx);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks to constructive critics/suggestions, I think this is a better solution.

Comment: Avoid accessing the context in the constructor of the controller. It should only be accessed after the controller has been completely initialized.

Comment: Of course, this is just to give an idea of how to get access to the HttpContext object. The user is surely calling GetClientID() somewhere else in their code.

Comment: Then explicitly demonstrate that in your code in case someone else takes this example as how they should do it.

Comment: @Bigabdoul. thanks for comment in asp.net core ..i have used GetClientID method in another controller

Comment: i am new in aps.net core so i am just following this site please check  http://blog.geveo.com/OAuth-Implementation-for-WebAPI2

Comment: public IHttpActionResult GetProperty(int propertyID)
        {
            int clientID = OwinContextExtensions.GetClientID();
            try
            {
                //var result = Service or DB Call(clientID, propertyID)
                return Json(new
                {
                    PropertyName = string.Format("Property - {0}", propertyID),
                    Success = true
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }

Comment: in above comment i have posted my controller where i have used OwinContextExtensions.GetClientID() method after youe suggestion its gives error here

Comment: can anyone suggest me asp.net core code link for OAuth 2.0. i would highly appreciate it.

Comment: What's the name of your controller and what does its constructor look like?

Comment: There is little benefit injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` in a controller since you already have a `HttpContext` property within each controller. The name `OwinContextExtensions` is also quite misleading since this isn’t actually OWIN. If you need the `HttpContextAccessor` then it should also generally be registered as a singleton; you can do so by simply calling `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`.

Comment: Hey @poke, the snippet in the controller is intended to show how to inject the HttpContext into a class. And I used to think that the context is request-based hence the transient registration when it should in fact be a singleton. I just picked up the "OwinContextExtensions" name from the questioner; but you're right it's confusing after removing the OwinContext code. Thanks for the suggestions.